# How To Redirect IPS 4.x urls to XenForo 2 with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, xenforo, ipb

my old urls is
example.com/topic/**123456789**-my-title-here/

and my new url is:
example.com/threads/my-title-here.**123456789**/

how i can redirect old url to new url with htaccess

note:
how i can split only numbers from old url, can use this address for new urls :
example.com/threads/**123456789**/

i using xenforo 2

Answer (score 0):

i resolve the problem with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(\d+)-(.+)/page-(\d+)$ /forums/$2.$1/page-$3? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/(\d+)-(.+)/$ /forums/$2.$1/? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^topic/(\d+)-(.+)/page-(\d+)$ /threads/$2.$1/page-$3? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^topic/(\d+)-(.+)/$ /threads/$2.$1/? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)-(.+)/$ /members/$2.$1/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

add this codes below *`RewriteEngine On`* on `.htaccess` file